# Как из json-файла получить непосредственно строку байт в Python?

Tags: json, unicode, python-3.8, esc

Дан некоторый json-файл, например example.json и надо из него достать сразу "сырые" данные без преобразования их в словарь, как это делает `json.load(open('example.json'))`. При этом, если в файле содержатся unicode-escape последовательности, то не добавлять к ним доп. слэши (пример на рисунке ниже - строка на входе и строка на выходе).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас с подобной задачей справляюсь следующим образом:

```py
# получаю данные из файла
with open('example.json') as json_file_object:
    data_dict = json.load(json_file_object)
# преобразую их в строку байт (требуется также исключить пробелы)
data_bytes = json.dumps(data_dict, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')
# и избавляюсь от дополнительных слэшей
data_bytes = data_bytes.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf-8')
```

Можно ли как-то упростить или улучшить данный код? Буду благодарен любой помощи, включая указания, куда стоит "копать".

P.S.: В вопросе не учитывал обработку исключений/ошибок, т.к. проблема именно в преобразовании.

Comment: Выглядит странным применение дважды encode(utf-8).  Не вернёт ли обратно escape последовательности в строку повторное применение после decode?

Comment: В целом я относительно долго искал, как можно решить обозначенную задачу и попробовал разные варианты - в итоге сработал только указанный способ. Стоит учесть, что в исходном json-файле unicode автоматически заменяет кириллицу, но латиница не меняется (это я изменить не могу, т.к. обращаюсь к стороннему сервису)

Comment: но почему не сделано сразу после dumps decode?
      json_str = json.dumps(d).decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf8')

Comment: json.dumps(d) возвращает строку (str) с json, а decode можно применить только к  строке байт (bytes). Если сделать как вы указали выше, то получим: Unresolved attribute reference 'decode' for class 'str'